# Normal subgroup of prime power order

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $|G|=p^nm$ where $p$ is a prime and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^n$. IF $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$, show that $K \subseteq H$.

I have seen other solution, but I want someone to look at my solution and check if I have made any mistakes.

Consider cosets of sub group $H$, any element belonging to any cosets of $H$, other than H itself, must have order $s.p^k$, where $s$ divides m, since order of a coset  element in quotient group divides order of that element in group. And thus all elements whose order is $p^k$ form must be within H.

Am I right, if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Not all elements in H will have an order of $sp^k$ they could have any order of the form $sp^t$ where $t\le n$. This is the second sylow theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems there are a few proofs here.

Comment: I was talking about cosets of H. H will have elements only prime power order, since H is of prime power order.

Comment: The statement that all elements must have order $sp^k$ is simply false. There is no reason why any element in the group should have order $p^k$. But even apart from that, your final sentence "And thus ..." does not follow, because you could have $s=1$.

Comment: I understand your argument now, but the use of $p^k$ is wrong. For any $g \in G \setminus H$, the order of $gH$ as an element of $G/H$ is $s$ where $1<s$ and $p$ does not divide $s$. So the order of $g$ is $sp^i$ for some $i$. But all elements of $K$ have order a power of $p$, so they must all lie in $H$.

Comment: Yes. I should have used letter i. Other than that, is everything correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you look at the quotient $G/H$? This group has an order that is *not* divisible by $p$. Consider the image $KH/H (\cong K/(H \cap K))$. What can you say about this subgroup of $G/H$?

Comment: Ok. But I have to prove that KH forms a group right? Can you please have a look at my solution? Where can I read more about internal products?

Comment: Ok, I proved KH is a group. But I still have trouble with KH/H. I got that it is a subgroup of G,  but I don't see how the nature of order of K comes in to picture.

Comment: Yes $KH$ is a subgroup and as I indicated, by the first isomorphism theorem, $KH/H \cong K/(H \cap K)$ is a $p$-group. Since $G/H$ has a cardinality not being divsible by $p$, $KH/H$ must be trivial ($H/H=\bar{1})$. Hence $KH=H$ and it follows that $K \subseteq H$.